# Kunstraub oder Kunstdiebstahl

Tags: word-usage

*Raub* ist im Gegensatz zu *Diebstahl* mit Gewaltanwendung verbunden. Ich denke dabei nicht allein an die juristische Definition. Die Wörterbücher sagen:

> *rauben* (Eigentum eines anderen) widerrechtlich und unter Anwendung oder Androhung von Gewalt in seinen Besitz bringen ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rauben))
>
> *rauben* etw., jmdn. gewaltsam in seinen Besitz bringen, etw. jmdm. unter Anwendung oder Androhung von Gewalt wegnehmen ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/rauben))
>
> **Pfeiffer:** Raub m. ‘das Rauben, gewaltsame Wegnahme, geraubtes Gut, Beute’, ahd. *roub* (8. Jh.), asächs. *-rōf* (in *nōdrōf*) ‘gewaltsame Entreißung, Beute, Raub’ (unter DWDS oben)

Dennoch wird in den Medien, wenn Kunst gestohlen wird, oft von *Kunstraub* gesprochen.

Hat *Raub* in der Zusammensetzung seine ursprüngliche Bedeutung verloren oder handelt es sich, Kunstraub im Krieg ausgenommen, um ungenaue, möglicherweise sensationalisierende Sprache?

Darüber hinaus frage ich mich, wie sich die enorme Zunahme des Begriffs im Verhältnis zu *Kunstdiebstahl* seit 1980 erklärt, die auf [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kunstraub%2CKunstdiebstahl&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3) zu erkennen ist.

[image: Google Ngrams für "Kunstraub", "Kunstdiebstahl"]

Comment: Umgangssprachlich werden oft Begriffe wie "ausgeraubt", "ermordet" etc. verwendet, auch wenn der Sachverhalt nicht der juristischen Definition entspricht. Ich denke es wird genau daher rühren.

Comment: Ich würde nicht davon ausgehen, dass die juristische Bedeutung eine Wortes die ursprüngliche ist.

Comment: Ich gehe davon aus, dass das gewaltsame Öffnen einer Tür oder Überwinden von Sicherheitsmechanismen schon als *Gewalt* zählt, was bei gesicherten Riesengoldmünzen sicher zutrifft. Den Diebstahl sehe ich eher bei einem kleinen Dorfmuseum, wo es keinen nennenswerten Widerstand zu überwinden gilt, oder als Überbegriff, wenn man das Maß an Gewalt nicht thematisieren will.

Comment: Vergleiche: https://www.sprachnudel.de/woerterbuch/raubmordkopierer

Comment: Wieso hast Du den Cut bei 2000 gemacht - sollten wir nicht sehen, dass KR bei 2010 wieder eingebrochen ist? Wie Du siehst schwanken die Zahlen beträchtlich, das Verhältnis war 1980 etwa 7:1, 2000 17:1 aber auch 1984 schon 16:1.

Comment: Die Frage ist nicht, inwieweit eine vermeintliche Verschiebung der Bedeutung von "Raub" NUR in Bezug auf Kunst stattgefunden hat, sondern inwieweit der Unterschied zw. "Raub" und "Diebstahl" in allen Bereichen überhaupt noch Gültigkeit hat. Das hat nichts mit "sensationaliesierende(r)" Sprache zu tun, sondern mit Sprachgebrauch.

Answer (score 5):

Ich würde [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kunstraub%2C%20kunstdiebstahl&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKunstraub%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKunstdiebstahl%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CKunstraub%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKunstdiebstahl%3B%2Cc0) hier mit Vorsicht genießen. Schaut man sich die Bücher an, die von Google als Verweise verlinkt werden sind dies in erster Linie Bücher über den systematischen Kunstraub während der NS-Zeit.

Schaut man sich den [DWDS-Korpus](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kunstraub) der [ZEIT](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=zeit;q=Kunstraub), bzw [Berliner Zeitung](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=bz;q=Kunstraub) an, dann würde ich auch sagen, dass deren Beispiele sich auch eher auf tatsächlichen "Raub" beziehen statt auf Diebstahl.

Ich will allerdings nicht ausschließen, dass deine Beobachtung in gewisser Weise richtig ist. Gründe für die Benutzung von Kunstraub (obwohl es rechtlich ein Diebstahl ist) wären etwa

- kürzeres Wort (Zeitungsüberschriften kämpfen um jeden Buchstaben)
- reißerischer (Raub verkauft sich besser als Diebstahl)
- SEO - Suchmaschinenoptimierte Überschriften (es wird eher nach Raub statt nach Diebstahl gegooglet, auch wegen der Kürze des Worts)

Comment: Du müsstest dazu bei der Zeit dann aber auch im gesuchten Zeitraum suchen, also 1980-2000. Wenige spektakuläre Einzelfälle (Mona Lisa, Gurlit) sorgen rasch für Ausreißer, oder der Handel mit Kunst aus Irak und Syrien, der eng an die Kriege dort geknüpft ist.

Comment: Mein Eindruck ist, dass der Begriff "Raub" in Zusammensetzungen großzügiger verwendet wird als beim Einzelwort. Man denke an Begriffe wie Raubkopie, Raubdruck usw., wo gar keine Gewalt im Spiel ist.

Answer (score 3):

Die juristische Unterscheidung zwischen Raub und Diebstahl ist für den Sprachgebrauch eher irrelevant.

Ein "Kunstraub" ist (nach meinen beschränkten juristischen Kenntnissen) in aller Regel ein Einbruchdiebstahl, bei dem sich ein Dieb gewaltsam Zutritt in einen Raum verschafft. Diese Gewaltkomponente (die sich freilich nicht gegen Personen richtet)  dürfte eine Erklärung dafür sein, von einem Kunstraub zu sprechen. Ein ähnliches Beispiel ist *Raubgrabung*. In diesem Fall wird jedoch noch nicht einmal Gewalt angewandt.

Eine psychologische Erklärung ist außerdem, dass ein Raub als schlimmer als ein Diebstahl betrachtet wird. Für viele Menschen ist es ein äußerst schlimmes Delikt, wenn unersetzliche Stücke aus einem Museum gestohlen werden. Der juristische Laie wird daher mit gewisser Berechtigung das Wort **Kunstraub** dem Wort **Kunstdiebstahl** vorziehen.

Comment: Doch, "rücksichtslos angewandte Macht" als Definition von Gewalt passt sehr wohl auf Raubgrabung - der Boden spukt es nicht freiwillig aus. Es liegt auch nicht offen rum.

Comment: Genau, denn Kunst ist i.d.R. immer gut gesichert und für die Überwindung der Türen, Gitter usw. ist Gewalt nötig.